# Use definition order of Enum as natural order

Tags: python, enums, natural-sort

I'm trying to create an `Enum` subclass whose values use their definition order as their natural sort order, like in the example below:

```
@functools.total_ordering
class SelectionType(enum.Enum):
     character = 'character'
     word = 'word'
     sentence = 'sentence'
     paragraph = 'paragraph'

     def __le__(self, other):
          if not isinstance(other, SelectionType):
                return NotImplemented

          return self._positions[self] < self._positions[other]

SelectionType._positions = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(SelectionType)}
```

Is there a more direct way to get the position of an enum value in its definition order or otherwise a better way to do this?

Comment: Careful with aliases

Comment: There is a library, ordered_enum, just for this:

https://blog.yossarian.net/2020/03/02/Totally-ordered-enums-in-python-with-ordered_enum

Answer (score 7):

If this is a pattern you need often, or if the values are important and cannot be replaced by numbers, make a custom Enum you can inherit from:

```
import enum

class ByDefinitionOrderEnum(enum.Enum):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        try:
            # attempt to initialize other parents in the hierarchy
            super().__init__(*args)
        except TypeError:
            # ignore -- there are no other parents
            pass
        ordered = len(self.__class__.__members__) + 1
        self._order = ordered

    def __ge__(self, other):
        if self.__class__ is other.__class__:
            return self._order >= other._order
        return NotImplemented

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if self.__class__ is other.__class__:
            return self._order > other._order
        return NotImplemented

    def __le__(self, other):
        if self.__class__ is other.__class__:
            return self._order <= other._order
        return NotImplemented

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.__class__ is other.__class__:
            return self._order < other._order
        return NotImplemented
```

This allows you to keep any other value instead, while still sorting according to definition order.

```
class SelectionType(ByDefinitionOrderEnum):

     character = 'character'
     word = 'word'
     sentence = 'sentence'
     paragraph = 'paragraph'
```

and in use:

```
>>> SelectionType.word < SelectionType.sentence
True

>>> SelectionType.word.value < SelectionType.sentence.value
False
```

Comment: Thanks. I was exactly looking for this kind of an Enum for Django model choices. You sir are a godsend!

Answer (score 4):

You could encode the positions as values. Use `.name` to get the name.

```
class SelectionType(enum.Enum):
     character = 1
     word = 2
     sentence = 3
     paragraph = 4
     # copy the OrderedEnum recipe from https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#orderedenum
     def __lt__(self, other):
         if self.__class__ is other.__class__:
             return self.value < other.value 
         return NotImplemented

>>> SelectionType.word.name
'word'
>>> SelectionType.word < SelectionType.sentence
True
```

On Python 3.6+ you could use `enum.auto()` to avoid hard-coding the positions.

```
class SelectionType(enum.Enum):
    character = enum.auto()
    word = enum.auto()
    sentence = enum.auto()
    paragraph = enum.auto()
```

Comment: Personally, I would do a `from enum import Enum, auto` to avoid the `enum.` repetition.  Still worth a +1 though.  :)

Comment: @EthanFurman Absolutely. I'm trying to avoid `from` imports in short examples to to avoid confusion.

Comment: Why is this proposed instead of simply *using* an [`OrderedEnum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#orderedenum) ?

Comment: @wim It is just a recipe, there is *no* OrderedEnum in the `enum` module, if you want it, you need to copy-and-paste those code.

Comment: Ah, that would explain it!

Comment: @wim: If you use [`aenum`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum) then `OrderedEnum` is provided.

Comment: If you're going to define the enum values as integers, you might as well inherit from [`enum.IntEnum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.IntEnum) and save yourself the trouble of writing an `__lt__` method.

Comment: @Aran-Fey:  Using `IntEnum` (an any `Enum` with a mixed-in type) loses some of the protections of the `Enum` type.

Comment: About the snippet copied from the `OrderedEnum`: why are you `return`ing the `NotImplemented` instead of `raise`-ing it?

Comment: @PiCTo This is described in the documentation of [`object.__lt__()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__lt__#object.__lt__).